# How to show post counts of different categories by shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

i want to display multiple categories with their post counts with help of short code without plugin.

i found many functions code here but didn't work with multiple categories with shortcode.

how to create function that is use to display all categories post counts using shortcode.

**Example:**

```
category 1: 20 posts
category 2: 10 posts
category 3: 15 posts
```

the display results 20,10 or 15 should be shown by help of shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic way to show a list of categories with their post counts.  You could use other objects to link to the category pages etc.  From what you described you just need a list, but this is the foundation.

```
function category_post_count() {
    ob_start(); //php output buffer

    $categories = get_categories(); ?>

    <ul>

       <?php foreach($categories as $cat) { ?>


         <li><?php echo $cat->name . ': ' . $cat->count; . ' posts ';  ?></li>


       <?php  } ?>

    </ul>


     <?php $endBuffer = ob_get_clean(); 
     return $endBuffer;

}
add_shortcode( 'category_post_count', 'category_post_count' );
```

Then all you need to do is add this to the area where you want it to show up on the page...

```
[category_post_count]
```